# Set java home on windows registry level

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to execute either a powershell or batch file on a remote WIndows 2012 server to set java home & path permanently on a system level. I'm from Linux background, so finding it kind of challenging to get a solution.

I tried below powershell on my local, but of no use, I don't see JAVA on the Path or JAVA_HOME system variable created.

install_java.ps1

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\myfolder\ZuluJDK8")

$oldSysPath = (Get-Itemproperty -path 'hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment' -Name Path).Path
$newSysPath = $oldSysPath + ";$($Env:JAVA_HOME)\bin"

Set-ItemProperty -path 'hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment' -Name Path -Value $newSysPath
```

I referred to https://sites.google.com/site/forthenerdwithin/cool-scripts/cool-command-scripts but felt it's an overkill for my purpose.

Comment: The script you found seem pretty straight forward, what makes you feel it's "overkill"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set environment variables permanently, use the `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine` parameter (for short just the string 'Machine')

```
# set the JAVA_HOME environment variable
$javaPath = 'C:\myfolder\ZuluJDK8'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", $javaPath, "Machine")

# get the current PATH string, split it on ';' and add the new path to the array
$newPath = ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine") -split ';' | 
             Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }) + "$javaPath\bin" | Select-Object -Unique

# set the updated PATH environment variable by joining the array back again with ';'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", ($newPath -join ';'), "Machine")
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Setting an environment variable directly through the registry works, but you'd have to login again to see the effect.